# Why Redis 'Zset' means 'Sorted Set'?

Tags: python, redis, zset

When I was studying Redis for my database, I learned that 'Zset' means 'Sorted Set'.
What does 'Zset' actually stand for? I couldn't figure out why it also means 'Sorted Set'.

It could be simple or too broad question, but I want to understand exactly what I learned.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A similar question is asked before on Redis's github page and the creator of Redis [answered it](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/4024)

> Hello. `Z` is as in XYZ, so the idea is, sets with another dimension: the
> order. It's a far association...  I know :)

- Set commands start with `s`
- Hash commands start with `h`
- List commands start with `l`
- Sorted set commands start with `z`
- Stream commands start with `x`
- Hyperloglog commands start with `pf`

Comment: Thank you for good and precise answer! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 4):

Sorted sets could have been named sset, but it's unpronouncable, as well as ss has a bad connotation in Europe. So, maybe due to this, or just for fun they have chosen the [zset](http://www.meaningslike.com/name-stands-for/zset) name.

> The essence of the given name Zset stands for seriousness, thought, intuition, intent and wisdom.

So, it is highly probable that the chosen name has little to do with technology and more with culture. This is what I can work out from the sources available, but this is only probably true. If you need factual precision, then you might want to send a message to the authors, asking them.

Comment: Thank you for good answer! I think both of you give me good answer, but I have to choose one.. Thank you! Have a nice day.

Comment: @DaeeonKim you are welcome. I would also choose the other answer, because it is quoting the author, but will leave mine here, as it is highly probable that the name of Zset has to do something with the name chosen for sorted sets.